Why do most Litvishe circles in the US light Chanukah menorah by the window? It should either be outdoors, or on the table?
The Gemara (Shabbos 21b) says that you must light your Chanukah menorah near the doorway of your house on the outside. If you live on an upper floor, you should light it in your window. And in times of danger, you light the menorah on your table.
There are many explanations why many don't light outdoors these days, along the lines that we still have the original enactment of "times of danger" (see Sefer Haitur, Shibolei Haleket & Aruch HaShulchan). Mishnah Berurah 671:38 writes that if one is lighting inside, it is more correct, where possible, to light by a window, to fulfill pirsumei nisa. However, if we are still concerned about sakanah we should light on the table. If we are not concerned, then why shouldn't one light outdoors.

It's because we have clear glass windows so we can publicize the miracle to people inside and outside. Back then they had to pick and the gemara says prefer outside. (Their windows were holes in the wall with big wooden plugs. The attic dweller put his on the sill outside the plug.) The people who moved in the 20th century from windows to outside are hyper literalists who missed the point.

@DoubleAA are you sure that ashkenazim who moved to israel and began light outside are doing so for the motives you describe, rather than adopting the pre-existing sefardic practices they encountered?

@JoelK Hmm the local sefardim lit continuously outside in Israel? Id expect they also switched recently. I'm not sure off the cuff who switched first. Note I didn't claim Ashkenazim in my first comment.

@DoubleAA Right. We know ashkenazi practice was pretty uniformly to light inside for a long time. I don't know enough about the history of sefardic lighting practices

@JoelK I'd say Ashkenazi practice to light in a non-public way was universal for a long time, and then in the last few hundred years with the Enlightenment etc. they [often] resumed lighting publicly. Inside vs outside is not the relevant category but rather publicly vs privately.

I think they say Rav Moshe Feinstein, among others, who endorsed lighting in the window. But then again, you could claim "Rav Moshe said so" that for all sorts of contemporary American Orthodox standard practices, and you'd be right at least half the time.

@Shalom virtually all the non-chasidic acharonim since the invention of modern windows endorsed it. It's kind of a no brainer.

Even though the gemara discussed lighting on one's table, Rema to Orach Chaim 671:7 points out that the custom when lighting inside is still to light by the door (on the inside of the house) as was done when lighting outside.
Mishnah Berurah 671:38 writes that if one is lighting inside, it is more correct, where possible, to light by a window, to fulfill pirsumei nisa.

Not sure how this answers the question. Is it safe to mefarsem or not?

@DoubleAA OP seems to be assuming that a ground-floor dweller has only two options - outside the door or on one's table, and wants to know why contemporary US practice does not confirm to either option. I'm pointing out that they are presumably following MB - even if one cannot / will not light outside, for whatever reason, placing it at the window is preferable to lighting at one's table, where possible.

Note also that MA 671:8 seems to assume that there is a level of danger which would not allow lighting outside, but would allow lighting at a window.

Surely any possible type of danger is possible (tsunami, Zoroastrians, meteors, etc.) so that's no chiddush, but you claim nowadays that's the exact kind of danger widespread in the US (in areas where litvaks live)? Seems completely ludicrous to me.

No I'm not claiming that. Are you claiming that in general, contemporary litvishe society is known for making large-scale and deliberate changes to practice due to changes in realia, rather than sticking to what they've always done, and what a superficial read of the books would seem to imply?

Lol ok so your answer is "you forgot to account for a possible type of danger where window is safe but outside isn't and US Litvaks appear stuck there bc that was [apparently] common historically in lands they came from". If so it's not just "preferable" to light in windows but literally commanded since it's not  (/was not) danger

Logically it's hard to disagree with that assessment. Do you think the MB's language of נכון יותר supports that analysis?

Their issue is the Rama's ואין לשנות. MB (and MA and chayei adam, and everyone else who lived after the ~17th century when glass windows became more popular than pogroms) are saying it's better to switch to lighting publicly than to observe the (halachicly meaningless) custom of interior doorways even though the Rama said not to change it. And so that's understandably what most Jews did and Shalom Al Yisrael. (All the kulas about timing chashad etc. since "we light inside" [read: "we light privately"] don't apply anymore to those who light in windows [read: publicly].)

@Joel k, You make a good point with the Mishna Berura. But the question is then specifically on his opinion, why light by the window. If it is not dangerous anymore, then why not light outside. If it is still dangerous, how can we light by the window

Ill edit the question to reflect your comment

@sfeksfeika As pointed out above, the answer to your question is either that they assume there is/was a danger that was relevant to lighting outside but not relevant to people lighting inside, or you assume modern windows are actually better than lighting outside (which, measuring by the number of people who see the lights, is objectively true)

"writes that if one is lighting inside" I don't see that condition in the MB.

@DoubleAA if one’s home does not have a window overlooking the reshut harabim, where is the most correct place to light according to MB?

@DoubleAA I believe the Minchas Asher writes something to that effect. That sakana can also refer to the wind and cold outside. Therefore, that is also applicable today. So we still don't light ouside. But we light by the window, since there is no danger.

@sfeksfeika As noted above, that's a trivial point of extremely dubious applicability in virtually any (lower 48) US city.

@JoelK He doesn't specify afaict. Logically it should be wherever it will be seen the most. It seems obvious to guess he'd personally have lit inside by an interior door, but the question is is that because of some sakana in Radin, fervent traditionalism עוקר הלכה, or a prioritization of the inside people over the outside people (either practically because outsiders noticing/caring in Radin was minimal, or fundamentally because the gemara's preference may never have been binding
or because it doesn't apply anymore now that the people expect otherwise or something like that)
